# Expandir coluna Excel Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Criei esta classe com o código necessário para simular o que eu preciso. A necessidade é gerar um arquivo Excel com alguns dados e, que a célula ( tamanho da céula) seja o suficiente para acomodar o texto.
Na maioria dos posts encontrei a indicação para usar:

> sheet.autoSizeColumn(0)

Também

> CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle()
>
> style.setWrapText(true)
>
> cell.setCellStyle(style)

mas o `setWrapText` faz a quebra de texto automaticamente, e não é o que eu queria.

Não consegui o resultado desejado. Gostaria de indicações do que posso fazer para resolver.

Update:
Usando este trecho de código:

```
   // style.setWrapText(true);
    Cell cellSer1 = row.createCell(0);
    // cellSer1 = row.createCell(0);
    cellSer1.setCellStyle(style);
    String myCellSer1 = "Nota Fiscal";
    String text = myCellSer1;
    int width = text.length();
    sheet.setColumnWidth(0, width * 250);
    String stringCellValueSer1 = myCellSer1;
    cellSer1.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer1);
```

Consegui algo, já posso alterar o tamanho da coluna, porém é trabalhoso,e creio não ser uma boa solução.

Update2:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This
>   worksheet does not contain merged regions     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getMergedRegions(XSSFSheet.java:1116)
>     at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getCellWidth(SheetUtil.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidthForRow(SheetUtil.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getColumnWidth(SheetUtil.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:400)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(XSSFSheet.java:382)
>     at view.XLSTest.main(XLSTest.java:98)

Update3:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class XLSTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
 HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheetName");
 File file;
 file = new File("C:\\Temp\\Notas.xls");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

 HSSFRow row;
 int count = 0;
 String posicaoExcel = null;

 row = sheet.createRow((short)count);

 Cell cellSer1 = row.createCell(0);
 String myCellSer1 = "Nota Fiscal";
 String stringCellValueSer1 = myCellSer1;
 cellSer1.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer1);

 Cell cellnf1 = row.createCell(1);
 String myCell1 = "Série";
 String stringCellValue1 = myCell1;
 cellnf1.setCellValue(stringCellValue1);

 for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
     count++;
     posicaoExcel = "longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggg";

     row = sheet.createRow((short)count);
     Cell cellSer = row.createCell(0);
     String myCellSer = posicaoExcel;
     String stringCellValueSer = myCellSer;
     cellSer.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer);


     Cell cellnf = row.createCell(1);       
     String myCell = posicaoExcel;
     String stringCellValue = myCell;
     cellnf.setCellValue(stringCellValue);
 }

 int quantidadeColunas = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
 for(int i = 0; i < quantidadeColunas; i++ ) {
      sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
 }

 try {
     wb.write(fos);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(XLSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

 try {
     fos.flush();
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(XLSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XLSTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheetName");
        File file;
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\Lucio\\Documents\\Notas.xls");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        XSSFRow row;
        int count = 0;
        String posicaoExcel = null;

        XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        row = sheet.createRow(count);

        Cell cellSer1 = row.createCell(0);
        // cellSer1 = row.createCell(0);
        cellSer1.setCellStyle(style);
        String myCellSer1 = "Nota Fiscal";
        String stringCellValueSer1 = myCellSer1;
        cellSer1.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer1);
        // sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

        Cell cellnf1 = row.createCell(1);
        // cellnf1 = row.createCell(1);
        String myCell1 = "Série";
        cellnf1.setCellStyle(style);
        String stringCellValue1 = myCell1;
        cellnf1.setCellValue(stringCellValue1);

        //sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            count++;
            posicaoExcel = "longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggg";

            row = sheet.createRow(count);
            Cell cellSer = row.createCell(0);
            // cellSer = row.createCell(0);
            String myCellSer = posicaoExcel;
            String stringCellValueSer = myCellSer;
            cellSer.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer);
            cellSer.setCellStyle(style);
            // sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

            Cell cellnf = row.createCell(1);
            //cellnf = row.createCell(1);
            String myCell = posicaoExcel;
            String stringCellValue = myCell;
            cellnf.setCellValue(stringCellValue);
            cellnf.setCellStyle(style);
            // sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

        }

        //loop para alterar o tamanho da coluna
        int t = count;
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(t);
        }

        try {
            wb.write(fos);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XLSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            fos.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(XLSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do seu for pra alterar o tamanho da coluna é que ele usa como base o valor de linhas, não o de colunas.

Para pegar a quantidade de colunas, pode usar o método `getPhysicalNumberOfCells()`

```
 int quantidadeColunas = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
 for(int i = 0; i < quantidadeColunas; i++ ) {
      sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
 }
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo:

```
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
 XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheetName");
 File file;
 file = new File("C:\\Temp\\Notas.xls");
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

 XSSFRow row;
 int count = 0;
 String posicaoExcel = null;

 row = sheet.createRow(count);

 Cell cellSer1 = row.createCell(0);
 String myCellSer1 = "Nota Fiscal";
 String stringCellValueSer1 = myCellSer1;
 cellSer1.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer1);

 Cell cellnf1 = row.createCell(1);
 String myCell1 = "Série";
 String stringCellValue1 = myCell1;
 cellnf1.setCellValue(stringCellValue1);

 for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
     count++;
     posicaoExcel = "longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggg";

     row = sheet.createRow(count);
     Cell cellSer = row.createCell(0);
     String myCellSer = posicaoExcel;
     String stringCellValueSer = myCellSer;
     cellSer.setCellValue(stringCellValueSer);


     Cell cellnf = row.createCell(1);       
     String myCell = posicaoExcel;
     String stringCellValue = myCell;
     cellnf.setCellValue(stringCellValue);
 }

 int quantidadeColunas = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
 for(int i = 0; i < quantidadeColunas; i++ ) {
      sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
 }

 try {
     wb.write(fos);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

 try {
     fos.flush();
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: Adicionei seu código, porém deu a exception que coloquei em update2

Comment: O código utilizado é praticamente o mesmo. Minha unica alteração, além da apontada, é que removi tudo relacionado a `style`

Comment: Vou checar isso

Comment: Não deu certo aqui, mesmo removendo os trechos relacionados a `style` vou procurar em casa mais tarde se consigo fazer funcionar.

Comment: Adicionei o código completo no final da resposta.

Comment: Código versão  final em "update 3", foi preciso alterar de `XSSF`para `HSSF`, dessa forma funcionou como desejado, obrigado pelas dicas.